# How to include applicationId in command line call from build.gradle dependency?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to follow [this Gist for disabling system animations](https://gist.github.com/xrigau/11284124#file-build-gradle-L24):

```
task grantAnimationPermission(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'installDevDebug') {
    commandLine "adb shell pm grant $android.defaultConfig.applicationId android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE".split(' ')
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith('installDevDebugAndroidTest')) {
        task.dependsOn grantAnimationPermission
    }
}
```

This code is trying to use `adb` to grant the `SET_ANIMATION_SCALE` permission whenever a debug build is run (an alternative to the above code would be fine too).

Unfortunately, when I run it, the `applicationId` always comes out as null:

```
$ ./gradlew installDevDebugAndroidTest
<snip>
:CookBrite:grantAnimationPermission
Bad argument: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: null
```

If I print `$android.defaultConfig`, it seems to confirm the applicationId is null:

```
ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, minSdkVersion=ApiVersionImpl{mApiLevel=14, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=ApiVersionImpl{mApiLevel=21, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=119, versionName=1.1.4, applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}
```

This is even though my working build.gradle happily supports changing the package name for all my build flavors.  Help!

I also tried wrapping these new parts of the build.gradle in an `afterEvaluate` section, but that seems to stop them from running (possibly because `tasks.whenTaskAdded` won't work after evaluation).